# jmeter recording session javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, jmeter

I have to record a user session for make a performance test. I use JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, but it is not working with javascript and jquery, I have the error in the picture:

> JQuery is not defined.

[image: Error with jquery]

I have 2 questions:
 1. **How can I bypass this error?**
 2. **AreThere are another program that i can use for recording session and import it into jmeter?**

Thank you for all.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter is not a browser and hence it can not execute the Java script.If you want to calculate the performance of your client side than use plugins for the same.

Comment: I know jmeter is not a browser but i need to record user navigation. In my scenario I have a website that use jquery for submit request to server, how can i record this? Is it possible? Which plugin do you suggest me?